# Android hardkey keyboard

Tags: android, android-fragments, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, android-keypad

I have hardkey dialpad through which I want to enter number as well as alphabets, like a old dial pad mobile phone.

Now I want is, that when I enter text in edittext, a small keyboard or fragment should pop up showing all options possible right next to the edit text.

For ex. if I press 2, it should show |2|A|B|C| right next to edit text.

Any ideas on how to implement this?

Comment: I started to answer, and then realized it was way too broad to do so.  I'd have several pages of text.  What specific part of it do you need help on?

Comment: I mean should i use the standard keyboard or should i use a frame layout that dynamically adds corresponding button to views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

I declared a Linear Layout in my activity_main.xml

after doing that I programatically add required buttons to a dynamically created view and then add that view to the original layout dynamically, along with moving it with the cursor.

That solves my problem